# Rails 4 -- Searching in the console - form of expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I'm trying to figure out how to search in my console.

```
UserOrganisationMapperService.call(User.where(email: ‘hello@trcr.com’).first)
```

I tried the above. This format of expression has previously worked for me, although now I'm getting error messages that I just can't figure out.

```
SyntaxError: (irb):7: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...where(email: ‘hello@trcr.com’).first)
...                               ^
(irb):7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
...ail: ‘hello@trcr.com’).first)
```

I've managed to figure out that "tIVAR" means instance variable. The rest I can't figure out. I don't know what that means in the context of the line I put in the console.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
UserOrganisationMapperService.call(User.where(email: ‘hello@trcr.com’).first)
```

Try:

```
UserOrganisationMapperService.call(User.where(email: 'hello@trcr.com').first)
```

I suspect `‘` is being treated as a special character (as opposed to `'`).